# export whole database data to json format for nosql database

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm, nosql

currently I'm having a database with lots of records (around 3000)

i want want to export the whole database for using it as a nosql database on a mobile-app with nosql technologies like couchdb or something like this.

what is the best way to do such an export?

my approach was to get the data via doctrine and then do some json-encode, but this results in a very long lasting request which ends up in a crash of my application server (apache)

my second approach would be a manual export of the whole database to json format and parse it on my mobile-app, but isn't there another way?

Comment: Is it possible to export data with PHPMyAdmin and insert it into CouchDB?

Comment: I did not tried that but that was somehow also my second intention... But ideally I want to build my structure on my own (there are some manytomany connections, so I want to build the json directly to remove these foreign keys etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what causes the server to crash? Are you using up your memory or something?  I think in your case you might try getting the information in chunks, format your data, then write it to a file.  Something that can take a while, but doesn't eat up too much system resources.

Comment: Cause of the crash is the export to json (not writing to file, just doing something similar to json_encode). Writing to a file would be the next step, I haven't done this until now, so there is no crash.

Answer (score 0):

Use CouchDB also on the current server. CouchDB can replicate to other instances if needed, which is a very painless transaction I am told, so if your data is already in Couch, you win.

Problem is: How to get it there, and this probably is a question of which data structure do you have, and the answer should probably be "each item at a time in a loop", and not "everthing in a giant JSON".

Comment: That's a bit silly, I don't want to move my whole db to nosql. I just want to have an offline version of my database for my mobile-clients. That's nothing new.

Comment: Then why are you asking for something NOSQL like for your mobile clients? There are SQL databases as well, like SQLite. These should be available for mobile platforms.

Comment: The keypoint is: I want to use nosql on my mobile apps, but normal relational database on my server. The mobile apps are readonly. And since I'm having a REST API which returns me good JSON, I was wondering why not to use something like nosql to do simple searches in my mobile app. i have never asked for a move from relational to nosql

Comment: You did. You just didn't specify which NOSQL db you want to use. But in reality you don't really need to export JSON for NOSQL, you just want to have a readonly dump of your database for offline browsing - in ANY format that allows it. Why don't you ask for THAT instead?

Comment: Yeah ok, I agree. BUT I have never asked for moving from relational db to nosql. so tell me now, how does it work if I have a relational db (let's say mysql) and I want to have an offline version of it easy importable for my mobile app. go for sqlite? I WANT NOSQL! THAT was the question.

Comment: You contradict yourself. "I never asked for moving to NOSQL" -> "I WANT NOSQL". Please come back with an update after you decided which NOSQL solution you will use. Some remarks: 1. NOSQL and JSON are not related! NOSQL does not automatically use JSON. NOSQL also is no defined branch of databases, it is "everything else but SQL" with a huge array of use cases. 2. Doctrine supports some NOSQL databases, for example CouchDB. 3. How does the data get to the device? How do updates take place? 4. Why don't you use the same NOSQL db on both ends?

Comment: What the? My main database is relational, i don't want to change that. But I want nosql for my mobile apps. Is that so hard to understand? According your questions/remarks: 1. jap, I know, I asked for a json to import it to a nosql database, which supports json (it's that easy), 2. again: i don't want to move to nosql 3. data via file download. 4. update from device to web-app (with main rel. db) will be processed on server, updates must be approved by a team anyway. 5.because I have already the whole sql database, I'm not starting with the development of a new application.moving=too expensive

Comment: Any why don't you install an "export and provision" database on your server that gets the data pushed from your relational database in usable pieces, and then replicate from there?

Comment: give me an example, what do you mean with export and provision? my idea was to create the "exportable" json file by doctrine and symfony (i'm using also some doctrine extensions etc.) and parse this json as my database. so I don't have to do that much on my mobile client.

Comment: Assuming you use CouchDB, the easiest way is to use it's replication feature. So you need two CouchDB instances, one on the device, and one on your server. So the problem of exporting the relational db transforms from "export to static file, download huge amount of data in one piece, import to local CouchDB on a mobile device" to "Move data into server-side instance of CouchDB and then let the client replicate". It's probably the same amount of initial data, but I think the transfer is more robust, and updating afterwards also is. And you can test the export without handling a mobile device.

Comment: But in that case, I have to setup couchdb and replication from rel db to couchdb?

Comment: You'd have to deal with CouchDB anyways. And you have to deal with moving the data from rel DB to CouchDB anyways. So only setting up a server instance of CouchDB is new.